# How to split sp|O00602|FCN1_HUMAN with (|)

Tags: r, split

How to split this string?

```
sp|O00602|FCN1_HUMAN
```

to

```
[[1]]
 [1]"sp","O00602","FCN1_HUMAN"
```

I used the following code

```
strsplit("sp|O00602|FCN1_HUMAN",split ="|")
```

However, the result I got is

```
[[1]]
 [1] "s" "p" "|" "O" "0" "0" "6" "0" "2" "|" "F" "C" "N" "1" "_" "H" "U" "M" "A" "N"
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `fixed= TRUE` so that `|` is interpreted as a literal string, not as  a regular expression:

```
strsplit("sp|O00602|FCN1_HUMAN",split ="|", fixed= TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The character `"|"` is a meta-character, so you need to escape it.

```
strsplit("sp|O00602|FCN1_HUMAN", split = "\\|")
#[[1]]
#[1] "sp"         "O00602"     "FCN1_HUMAN"
```